# Trying to implement linear regression in python

Tags: python, regression

I am implementing linear regression in Python, and I think I am doing something wrong while converting matrix to numpy array, but cannot seem to figure it out. 
Any help will be appreciated.

I am loading data from a csv file that has 100 columns. y is the last column. I am not using col 1 and 2 for regression.

```
communities=np.genfromtxt("communities.csv", delimiter = ",", dtype=float)
xdata = communities[1:,2:99]
x = np.array([np.concatenate((v,[1]))for v in xdata])
y = communities[1:,99]
```

Function definition

```
def standRegress(xArr, yArr):
    xMat = mat(xArr); yMat = mat(yArr).T
    xTx = xMat.T*xMat
    if linalg.det(xTx)==0.0:
        print"singular matrix"
        return
    ws = xTx.I*(xMat.T*yMat)
    return ws
```

calling the function

```
w = standRegress(x,y)
xMat = mat(x) #shape(1994L,98L)
yMat = mat(y) #shape (1L, 1994L)
yhat = xMat*w #shape (1994L, 1L)
```

Next I am trying to calculate RMSE and this is where I am having problem

```
yMatT = yMat.T #shape(1994L, 1L)
err = yhat - yMatT #shape(1994L, 1L)
error = np.array(err)
total_error = np.dot(error,error)
rmse = np.sqrt(total_error/len(p))
```

I get an error while I am doing the dot product and thus not able to calculate rmse. I will appreciate if someone can help me find my mistake.

```
Error: 
 ---> 11 np.dot(error,error)
 12 #test = (error)**2
 13 #test.sum()/len(y)
 ValueError: matrices are not aligned
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the specific error message you're receiving?

Comment: as you're using `numpy`, just wonder why if there is any particular reason you're not using `linalg`?

Comment: @Anzel, did not think of using linalg. Can you please guide how to use that.

Comment: @nasiajaffri, take a look at [this numpy doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy-linalg-lstsq)

Comment: @Michael0x2a, I have edited the question. Please have a look now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what the last `dot` is supposed to do. But you can't multiple `error` with itself this way. `dot` does a matrix multiplication, thus the dimensions have to align.

See, e.g., the following example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ones((3, 4))
B = np.ones((3, 4))
print np.dot(A, B)
```

This yields the error `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`.

What is possible, however, is:

```
print np.dot(A.T, B)
```

Output:

```
[[ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]]
```

---

In your example `error` is just a column vector - but stored as a 2D array:

```
A = np.ones((3, 1))
B = np.ones((3, 1))
print np.dot(A, B)
```

Same error.

So you can either transpose one argument - as shown above - or extract one column as a 1D array:

```
print np.dot(A[:, 0], B[:, 0])
```

Output:

```
3.0
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but err is supposed to be 1994 rows, but only 1 column. I am not sure what am I doing wrong before the dot product.

Comment: @nasiajaffri: Oh, I see. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: [Error: matrices are not aligned](http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~raoulb/teaching/PythonTutorial/frequent_errors.html#error-matrices-are-not-aligned)

Comment: Also - from ```np.info(np.dot)``` - ```...Raises
------
ValueError
    If the last dimension of `a` is not the same size as
    the second-to-last dimension of `b`....```